# "Не похожих" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> Все работы были выполнены в различных техниках, совершенно не похожих друг на друга.

Не похожих — слитно или раздельно? Почему? Мне кажется, что это прилагательное и надо писать слитно, зависимое слово *совершенно* усиливает утверждение.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Предпочтительно -- **слитное** написание, **но и раздельное -- не ошибка**.

В реальных текстах велика доля вариативности. См.:

*"не похожих друг на друга"* -- 15 700 результатов (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%22&tbm=bks ),

*"непохожих друг на друга"*  -- 23 300 результатов (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%22+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%22&tbm=bks ).

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже так думаю.

Все работы были выполнены в различных техниках, совершенно непохожих друг на друга. (различных)

Comment: Спасибо, что помогаете мне.